# Forward port and protocol from Apache subdomain?

Tags: apache-2.2, port-forwarding

I have never heavily configured my Apache setup at all. I only use Apache to host an ownCloud and Gitlab server, but Apache's taking the two most unblocked ports: 443 and 80. I want to use Apache to redirect all traffic from a subdirectory (`mysite.com/ssh` for example) and redirect everything to `localhost:22`. The solution must work with no configuration on anything but Apache. I simply want all requests sent to `mysite.com/ssh` then to `mysite.com:22` and then the ssh server only sees a request from 127.0.0.1. This should theoretically allow an ssh connection when all ports but 80 and 443 are blocked. Is this possible?

Comment: Not possible by default as stated as apache and ssh server work with different protocols so apache won't redirect ssh traffic directed to it. It could be done though with a tool like `proxytunnel`, otherwise perhaps you can run apache on just one port and reconfigure ssh to run on the freed port (not sure why you want ssh port blocked or if it's the hoster's policy, in this case perhaps you want to talk to them instead of circumventing them?)

Comment: See: http://www.rutschle.net/tech/sslh.shtml

Answer (score 1):

If you want to listen for both  HTTPS  and SSH protocols on port 443, you need to use software like http://www.rutschle.net/tech/sslh.shtml or https://github.com/stealth/sshttp . You can not do this with Apache alone for reasons Tero already explained.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. When you make a request to http(s)://mysite.com/ssh, the request is always made using HTTP / HTTPS protocol.

You would need a specially modified SSH client and server-side proxy to accomplish what you want.

The SSH client would have to encapsulate all SSH traffic into HTTP / HTTPS requests to the web server. The server side proxy would have to expand the traffic, and pass it to the SSH server on the box.

And I'm not 100% sure if even that is possible, because of SSH security.